# How to import a custom AWS rule

Tags: import, terraform, icmp

I'm trying to import a rule that looks like this in AWS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO8dv.png)

I tried a command like this but it fails:

```
terraform import aws_security_group_rule.ke_ingress_icmp  sg-0af205c29967e5084_ingress_icmp_-1_-1_0.0.0.0/0
    aws_security_group_rule.ke_ingress_icmp: Importing from ID "sg-0af205c29967e5084_ingress_icmp_-1_-1_0.0.0.0/0"...
    aws_security_group_rule.ke_ingress_icmp: Import prepared!
      Prepared aws_security_group_rule for import
    aws_security_group_rule.ke_ingress_icmp: Refreshing state... [id=sg-0af205c29967e5084_ingress_icmp_-1_-1_0.0.0.0/0]
    
    Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
```

I'm not sure how to represent protocol="Destination Unreachable" and port range="fragmentation required, and DF flag set" in the import command.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How does TF code for `ke_ingress_icmp` looks like?

Comment: I currently have it looking like this:   

    `resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ke_ingress_icmp" {
  type = "ingress"                 
  cidr_blocks      = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
  ]
  description      = ""
  from_port        = 0
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
  prefix_list_ids  = []
  protocol         = "-1"
  security_group_id  = aws_security_group.k8s_elb.id
  self             = false
  to_port          = 0
}`      

but it that shouldn't really affect the import as long as a corresponding resource block exists.